# Event and mysqldump

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-event

I am trying to create an event for automatic backup using this code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS e_AutomaticBackUp1Day
ON SCHEDULE AT 1 Day STARTS '2020-07-06 10:13:00'
DO
BEGIN
mysqldump -u user -p password dbname > E:BackUp.sql
END

$$
```

But I am getting an error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'day STARTS '2020-07-06 10:13:00'"

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666819/mysql-database-backup-automatically-on-a-windows-server or https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/automatically-backup-mysql-databases-on-windows-wamp

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` isn't a SQL statement but utility intended to be invoked from the OS command line.

If you want your DBs to be dumped on the schedule basis you have to create the `mydump.CMD` batch file and then to add this batch-file invocation in the windows scheduler. I see the `E:Backup.sql` path that is definitely windows-specific.

Comment: For non-Windows, use `cron`.